# Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView while Transaction to xml header

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, androidx

I work on an app with kotlin and androidx and i create setting class was working normally till it crash and give me that error in logcat

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.alserdar.evana, PID: 9425
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:658)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:801)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat.onCreateRecyclerView(PreferenceFragmentCompat.java:541)
    at androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat.onCreateView(PreferenceFragmentCompat.java:208)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:310)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1185)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1354)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1432)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1495)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:447)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2167)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1990)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1945)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1847)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2621)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2569)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:247)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:541)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1419)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7479)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3454)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Providing a LayoutTransition into RecyclerView is not supported. Please use setItemAnimator() instead for animating changes to the items in this RecyclerView
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutTransition(RecyclerView.java:2313)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.initFromAttributes(ViewGroup.java:730)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:662)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:655)
```

i tried to implement 
  `implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-preference-v14:1.0.0"`

and `implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'

  implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'`

i really tried every thing and i don't know from where that error coming i don't even use the recycleview

i tried to remove that line code `supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.settings, HeaderFragment())
            .commit()`

it open the class but without the views ..

my header class is that

```
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<Preference
        app:key="gifts"
        app:title="Gifts"
        app:icon="@mipmap/gift"
        app:fragment="com.alserdar.evana.b_home_stuff.setting_stuff.SettingsActivity$Gifts"/>


<Preference
        app:key="share"
        app:title="Share"
        app:icon="@mipmap/share"
        app:fragment="com.alserdar.evana.b_home_stuff.setting_stuff.SettingsActivity$Share"/>


<Preference
        app:key="buy_pin"
        app:title="Change Pin"
        app:icon="@mipmap/pin_code"
        app:fragment="com.alserdar.evana.b_home_stuff.setting_stuff.SettingsActivity$SyncFragment"/>

<Preference
        app:key="link_accounts"
        app:title="Link Accounts"
        app:icon="@mipmap/link"
        app:fragment="com.alserdar.evana.b_home_stuff.setting_stuff.SettingsActivity$LinkAccounts"/>


<Preference
        app:key="contact_us"
        app:title="Contact Us"
        app:icon="@mipmap/messages"
        app:fragment="com.alserdar.evana.b_home_stuff.setting_stuff.SettingsActivity"/>


<Preference
        app:key="add_country"
        app:title="Add Country"
        app:icon="@mipmap/plus"
        app:fragment="com.alserdar.evana.b_home_stuff.setting_stuff.SettingsActivity"/>
```

Comment: Have you add `implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'`?

Comment: Yeah.. Nothing happened and the same error

Comment: Can you add the XML code containing the RecyclerView?

Comment: I added the xml code above here and am not even use recycleview in this class or in any class in the app

Comment: Apparently one of the fragments used has a RecyclerViewer. You have to comment all of them and enable them one by one until you find which one it is and then look at its implementation.

Comment: You can also go back through your source control or Android Studio local history to a point where it worked to figure out what broke it.  If using local history you may want to take a backup of the current state first (and consider using source control even if you're the only developer on the project).

Comment: I've the same problem and did not find a solution yet...